# Testing custom template tag, Not able to import tags

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-templates

I'm not able to import custom template tag **check** in my test case. It is working if I test it manually through browser.

```
from django.template import Template
class CheckTagTest(TestCase):

    TEMPLATE = Template("""
        {% load roles_extra %} 
        {% check /demo/view1/ POST %}This will appear,.{% endcheck %}
        {% check /demo/view1/ GET %}This will not appear .{% endcheck %}"""
        )
    fixtures = ['test_check.json']

    def test_tag_correct(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(username='admin')
        rendered = self.TEMPLATE.render(Context({'user':user}))
```

It is **roles_extra** is not a valid tag library,

```
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\unittest\loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "<some_path>rolemanagement\roles\tests.py", line 40, in RegisterTest
    class CheckTagTest(TestCase):
  File "<some_path>rolemanagement\roles\tests.py", line 45, in CheckTagTest
    {% check /demo/view1/ GET %}This will not appear .{% endcheck %}"""
  File "<some_path>lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.nodelist = engine.compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "<some_path>lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\template\engine.py", line 261, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "<some_path>lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\template\base.py", line 341, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "<some_path>lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py2.7.egg\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1159, in load
    (taglib, e))
django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'roles_extra' is not a valid tag library: Template library roles_extra not found, tried django.templatetags.roles_extra,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.roles_extra,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.roles_extra,django_messages.templatetags.roles_extra,rest_framework.templatetags.roles_extra,djangular.templatetags.roles_extra,django_extensions.templatetags.roles_extra
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Which app is your `roles_extra` tag library in? Looking at the traceback, it looks like the app might be missing from your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting when the test runs. Could you be using different settings for running tests and production?

Comment: `roles_extra` is in `roles` app. It's location is according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout. I checked again, `roles` app is added under `INSTALLED_APPS`. I have only one setting file. It doesn't contain any test specific code.